# How to calculate time difference in seconds between two cells, where cells are formatted as text in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

How to calculate time difference in seconds between two text cells, where cells are formatted in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Thanks a million guys!

```
2019-03-21 09:53:56
2019-03-21 09:54:25
2019-03-21 14:10:36
2019-03-21 14:10:42
2019-03-22 11:49:16
2019-03-22 11:49:51
2019-03-22 11:50:21
2019-03-22 11:50:50
```

Comment: Suggest you to format the cells as Date/Time format and then use excel built-in date/time functions.

Comment: If you find the answers useful, then thank you is expressed by you voting them up... You can use the tick to accept one of them - helps the site keep track of answered questions. All this info is in the faqs available.

Answer (score 1):

If your date-times are entered as text, you can use something like this to convert them into values Excel can use for calculations:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10)) + TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

To convert a difference between two such values to seconds, multiply by 86400 (24*60*60)

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract two datetimes in excel you will get back the number of days as a decimal down to the accuracy of a second.

So `2019-03-21 09:53:56 -  2019-03-21 09:54:25` will give you: `0.000335648` as a return. You can multiply that time the number of seconds in a day to get your answer `0.000335648*24*60*60 = 29 seconds`.

In a formula this would be `=(A2-A1)*24*60*60`:

[image]